# Phalcon - Swiftmailer send email with invitation of event

Tags: php, phalcon, swiftmailer

I'm try to send a email on Phalcon adding an invitation with an event. This are the versions of my backend:

```
"phalcon/devtools": "^4.0",
"phalcon/migrations": "^1.2",
"swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^6.0",
```

Right now i can send emails and attach documents on this.

```
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
$message = (new Swift_Message($subject))
 ->setFrom([$from['email']=> $from['name'] ])
 ->setTo([$send_to['email'] => $send_to['name']])
 ->setBody($template, 'text/html');
$mailer->send($message);
```

I don't know if just add the file .ics this works ?

Comment: It's missing `->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('file.ics'))` after `->setbody`